# Add Related List Action Button "Send Engage Email" to custom Lead List LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, related-list, quickaction, pardot

The out of the box related list view doesn't work for what I need to have displayed for leads as I cannot filter it and only a limited amount of results show.

I have created an LWC which shows all of the information that I need to have displayed, but I don't know how to include the button to "Send Engage Email"   Having this button is absolutely critical to what my team needs.

This is the Send Engage Email that I need recreated.  My LWC is using a lightning-datatable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately once you go custom, you have to stay custom for the most part. Doing some googling leads me to believe that you are using Salesforce Engage part of Pardot. This will not be as simple few lines of code.

I'm not too familiar with Engage, but since it is part of Pardot, maybe you could build a button that calls an Apex method (@AuraEnabled) that calls this Pardot API - https://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-3/emails/#sending-one-to-one-emails

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping they would have pardot/engage methods already available in Apex, but I guess if not I can try to go this route.